# Drawing a line between two divs (multiple connections)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I have a div ("grid") full of images ("components"). I am able to drag and drop components onto the grid but now I want to be able to draw lines from one component to another. I am using a plugin called jsPlumb where you can pass a source div id and a destination div id and it will draw the line for you. I want the user to be able to make multiple connections to the different components so I am trying to allow a user to right click drag from one component to another and then create the connection. I am not sure how to do this...

```
$(document).on("mousedown",".component", function (e) {
    if (e.which == 3)
    {
       //I get can get the source id fine.
    }
}).on("mouseup", function (e) {
    if (e.which == 3)
    {
        //Cannot get the destination component id here
    }
});
```

Example of what it might look like:
[image]

I want to drag a connection from start to end.... What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the event object to get the ID on the mouseup.  Filter for right click or left or however you wanna do it, but this is the basics of grabbing the id

```
$(document).on("mousedown",".component", function (e) {
   var first_id = e.target.id;
}).on("mouseup", function (e) {
   var second_id = e.target.id;
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/57h1mfye/2/)

Comment: I noticed a wierd bug though.  It works fine if after the selection you click off of the objects.  But if you try to go back and forth, without clicking off the objects, it stops working.  So wierd.  ie, Click on element one and drag to 2.  Now click on element 2, and drag to 1.  Doesnt work.  But if you click off the elements, then do it.  It works

Answer (score 0):

the first can help you.

add it! i think it is flexible.

“$(this)” can help you to solve the question.

use $(this), you can get the element that you want to change it's style.

```
$(document).on('mousedown','.component', function (e) {
  $(this).css('background','blue');
  $('.chosen').html('Chosen ID:'+ $(this).html());
});
$(document).on('mouseup','.component', function (e) {
  $(this).css('background','yellow');
  $('.chosen').html("Chosen ID:"+ $(this).html());
});
```

[demo](http://output.jsbin.com/zaruhu)